# How do I store numbers in C++ without the decimals being truncated?

Tags: c++, calculator

I am writing a simple percentage calculator in C++. I am a beginner and I can't figure out how to store the decimals without them being removed. If I enter any input that results in a decimal, it changes to a 0 and messes up the rest of the calculation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 int result;
 cout << "Enter your goal: ";
 cin >> a ;
 cout << "Enter the amount achieved: ";
 cin >> b ;
 c = b / a;
 result = c * 100;
 cout << result;
 cin.get();
}
```

I know that the integer c is where the problem is, but I have know idea what I need to do to make this work. I don't know why I am having trouble with what should be a simple program.

Comment: Use the data type `double` instead of `int`.  There is also a data type `float` that would have been my answer if you had asked 20 years ago.  But now `float` should be viewed as an obscure alternative to `double` to be used when you both really need to save memory in storing a lot of them and really understand the rounding consequences of that choice.

Comment: Use `double` - it's a double precision number.

Comment: @erip: That's a completely unhelpful statement. What does "double precision" mean and how does it help? Double of what? The point is that `double` is a *floating point* type that is able to hold fractional numeric values.

Comment: Any number to zero? Sorry, I couldn't reproduce. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DMXWe273olYQzP7P

Comment: @erip that was so cool ...

Comment: @KerrekSB check  IEEE 754-1985. and then look for interchange formats.

Comment: @erip: LMGTFY links are banned, and working around them with bit.ly is akin to ban evasion. Don't do it. Thanks.

Comment: @KerrekSB OP can google double precision. It's a comment meant to get OP to do some research of his own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of a solution working for the wrong reasons.  Like @MikeCAT says in his answer, if you multiply by 100 first, it "works" (i.e. the result you get is not 0).  While that might look like a solution, it *isn't*, especially since multiplication should be commutative, right?  It doesn't make sense for the order of factors to change the answer.  It **shouldn't**.

## It works, right?

Well, yes, and no.  The real problem (like others have said) in your question is that you're not using data types the right way.  As I understand, you don't have much programming experience, which is cool.  Welcome to programming!  Computers are dumb, and when I say "dumb", I mean oh-my-god-you-are-the-stupidest-machine-ever dumb.

## A number is not always just a number

As other answers have mentioned, there are two main ways of handling numbers in programming (computers are so dumb that they need to be told which one to use): integers and floating points. Integers (as you probably know) are for the numbers in the set `{0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...}`.  They *cannot* represent rational numbers. Floating point numbers (or `float`s), represent rational numbers, up to a certain degree of exactitude.  The math behind floats is a bit complex (and I'm definitely not an expert), but basically, they allow you to represent a rational number up to a number of decimal points (since computer memory is limited, it is not possible to represent an infinite number of decimals).  `double`s like others have mentioned, pretty much just double the amount of decimal points you can specify.  Since memory was much more limited before, it was common to use `float`, but you can use `double` know without much worrying about it - and it's going to give you better results for calculation.  Note that there are *some* specific problems you can run into with `double`s and `float`s rounding and overflowing and all sorts of crazy stuff (which you should read about if you're doing more serious calculation), but in general, they're fine for most rational calculations.

The difference between these two data types is in the way they are represented in memory, when translated to binary.  Computers understand binary only, so everything needs to be translated so they can work with it.  You don't need to know the details right now, but in essence, the data type you choose *really* makes a difference.

## So what do I do?

Well, you have to know what sort of calculation you want to do, and what you want to use it for.  Sometimes, the language in which you program automates this choice (or chooses the more powerful version) for you, but in C++, that is not the case.  In C and C++, where your programming is closer to what computers understand than in other languages, you usually have to be much more specific (and careful) when programming.  That's also why programming in C and C++ tends to be considered as more difficult than others: less things are automated for you.

In your case, you probably don't really want integers.  When you use integers, it's *impossible* to use decimals.  So, when you divide, for instance `2 / 3`, the answer is `0` (with a remainder of `2`) - and when you multiply by `100` remains `0`.  We all know it's not *really* `0`, but the computer cannot represent `0.66` in an `int`.  It just can't.  So, it gives you the closest thing, which is `0`.  Now, if you do something like `100 * 2 / 3`, then the answer would be `66.6...`, which is represented as `66`.  The `.6` is lost, but the answer is no longer `0`.  So, it *appears* to "work", but it doesn't, really.  Even for percentages, there is a pretty big difference between `66%` and `66.66%`.

If you used `double`s, however, the story would be different.  In that case, `2 / 3` would be `0.6...`, and when you multiply *that* by `100`, then you get `66.6...`, which is the right answer.  That would be the **exact same** result as doing `100 * 2 / 3`.

## Putting it all together

So, your program should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 double a;
 double b;
 double c;
 double result;
 cout << "Enter your goal: ";
 cin >> a ;
 cout << "Enter the amount achieved: ";
 cin >> b ;
 c = b / a;
 result = c * 100;
 cout << result;
 cin.get();
}
```

This would work the right way, and you will have learned something cool in the process.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the basic numeric types:

```
int   -> integer numbers
float -> single precision floating point numbers
double-> double precision floating point numbers
```

You need the float or double ones for that operations.

Check some useful documentation:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "float" or "double" type to work with decimal point numbers.

A quick fix for your code is to change those int type variables to "float".

I also suggest you to read more about C++, like this post http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use floating point arithmetic something like:

```
double c = static_cast<double>(b) / a;
```

But if you just want the percentage as an integer, multiply by 100 *before* you divide:

```
int c = 100 * b / a;
```

Comment: @erip Supposed to be `int` having problems editting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (multiply `100` before dividing `b` by `a`):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 int result;
 cout << "Enter your goal: ";
 cin >> a ;
 cout << "Enter the amount achieved: ";
 cin >> b ;
 c = b / a;
 result = b * 100 / a;
 cout << result;
 cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I got it to work by multiplying by 100 first. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, if you do not need a perfect rounded result, is to first multiply with 100 and then divide by a

```
result = (b*100)/a;
```

If you need a rounded value you can first multiply all bei 10 and then round it manually

```
result = (((b*10*100)/(a*10))+5)/10
```

this statement can be shortened but I keep it that way to make it easier to understand.

The easiest way of yourse is using double values instead of int. But I do not know if it is your intense